# Classify specific numbers as Binary

Tags: r, binary

Have a dataset where a number of variables have been given a grade. 
Where grade:

- 0 = Missing,
- 1 = Fail
- 2 = Fail,
- 3 = Pass,
- 4 = Pass,
- 5 = Pass

I would like to change this to binary data in which 1-2 = 0 and 3-4 =1.
I have only found code where one number or a range of numbers are converted. Not specific numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
df$new_col <- as.integer(df$column_name %in% 3:4)
```

which is similar to doing :

```
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$column_name %in% 3:4, 1, 0)
```

Note that for the above 3,4 is changed to 1 and rest everything is turned to 0.

If you need to treat variables differently you can use `case_when` and specify conditions

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(cnew_col = case_when(column_name == 0 ~ NA_integer_, 
                              column_name %in% 3:4 ~ 1L, 
                              column_name %in% 1:2 ~0L, 
                              TRUE ~column_name))
```

Comment: thank you for such a quick answer! Just to see if I got this right. The first suggestion will take numbers 3-4 and turn them in to one? And the second suggestion will take  numbers 3:4 and turn them into one and all else into 0?

Comment: Both the suggestions i.e `as.integer` and `ifelse` will turn 3:4 to 1 and rest all to 0. The `case_when` suggestion will be helpful if you want to treat every number differently.

Comment: Great! Thank you, it worked well :)